# What is a `char*`?

Tags: c++, pointers, types

What is a `char*`, exactly?  Is it a pointer?  I thought pointers had the asterisk before the identifier, not the type (which isn't necessarily the same thing)...?

Comment: C doesn't care about spaces, so `char *foo;` is the same as `char* foo;`

Comment: @PaulTomblin: C does care about spaces, just not in that particular case.  `char apple;` and `charapple;` are quite different.

Comment: My answer on a similar question: [What is a char*?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6823292/365102).

Comment: Not sure if the questions are duplicates since the other question talks more about strings, i.e. `const char* s = "test";`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is a pointer to a `char`.

When declaring a pointer, the asterisk goes after the type and before the identifier, with whitespace being insignificant. These all declare `char` pointers:

```
char *pointer1;
char* pointer2;
char * pointer3;
char*pointer4;    // This is illegible, but legal!
```

To make things even more confusing, when declaring multiple variables at once, the asterisk only applies to a single identifier (on its right). E.g.:

```
char* foo, bar;    // foo is a pointer to a char, but bar is just a char
```

It is primarily for this reason that the asterisk is conventionally placed immediately adjacent to the identifier and not the type, as it avoids this confusing declaration.

Comment: Why is it, then, that when declaring multiple pointers on one line you have to use an asterisk for each one?  For example, `char * Pointer1, * Pointer2;`.

Comment: I still do not understand why they designed it like that... `char*` seems much more natural to me (as a type).

Comment: @elusive: Yeah, me too :-) I often use `char*` myself, and limit myself to one declaration per line for clarity.

Comment: What is confusing me is how can `char*` be a string? A string is an `Array` of chars - So why can we write code like `const char* str = "Hello";` - `char*` is only pointing to a single char not a string of chars?

Comment: An array of contiguous characters has to start somewhere in memory. The `char*` is simply pointing to the first character of that string -- ('H' in this case) but after that char is another, and another, so the pointer can be interpreted as pointing to a (null-terminated) string.

Answer (score 16):

It is a pointer to a character. You can write either

```
char* bla;
```

or

```
char *bla;
```

It is the same.

Now, in C, a pointer to a char was used for strings: The first character of the string would be where the pointer points to, the next character in the address that comes next, etc. etc. until the Null-Terminal-Symbol `\0` was reached.

BUT: There is no need to do this in C++ anymore. Use std::string (or similar classes) instead. The char* stuff has been named the single most frequent source for security bugs!

Comment: i was about to post the same answer

Answer (score 1):

http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

The `*` character shows up in two distinct places when dealing with pointers. First, the type "pointer to T" is denoted by `T*` (appending `*` to the type name). Second, when dereferencing a pointer, which is done by prepending `*` to the name of the pointer variable that you want to dereference.

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace doesn't normally matter, so

```
char* suchandsuch;

char *suchandsuch;

char
*
suchandsuch;
```

are all the same.