# character pointer

Tags: c, string

Why this code does not work?

```
int main(){
  char *str ="abcde";
   scanf("%s",str);
  printf("%s",str);
}
```

but this works?

```
int main(){
  char str[] ="abcde";
   scanf("%s",str);
  printf("%s",str);
}`
```

Comment: This question is answered by a [SOFAQ entry](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/faq#stringliterals)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first code, you declare a pointer, which points to a [string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal): `"abcde"`.

This might be a constant, and you will not be able to change it.

The second code is declaring an array and filling it with `['a','b',c','d','e','\0']`, and is not a constant - so you can change it.

Comment: can the input for str[] case take more values than the size with which it initialized(6 in this case).

Comment: @gaurav: I did not understand the question [in comment], can you clarify it?

Comment: I think he's asking if the array is of size 6 can the input take more than 6 characters. Which the answer is yes and you must carefully check for that.

Comment: yeah.i was asking that coz we are not specifying the size here..it seems it accepts few more characters unitl there is no more free continuous space

Comment: @gaurav: You are guaranteed to have array of the size of the string [including the '\0']. Everything other then that - is undefined behavior - it might work and it might fail.

Answer (score 4):

Because `char *str ="abcde";` is a pointer to string literal which is most likely stored in read-only memory.

`char str[] ="abcde";` is an array initialized with `"abcde"`.

You should also check out [Difference between char* and char[]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7564033/1168156)

Comment: String literals are not `const`. They just (may be) in read-only.

Comment: *"An ordinary string literal has type "array of n const char" and static storage duration."*

Comment: That's C++ standard. We are talking about C. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2245983/1055952

Comment: @asaelr: Nice one. I thought it's same in C. I have edited my answer, it should be OK now.

Comment: Note that "read-only memory" in this context probably doesn't mean hardware ROM; it's more likely just a segment of memory that's write-protected by the OS.  (Though it could be actual ROM on an embedded system.)

Answer (score 1):

> When string value is directly assigned to a pointer, it’s stored in a
>   read only block(generally in data segment) that is shared among
>   functions
>
> ```
> char *str  =  "GfG";
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> char str[] = "GfG";  /* Stored in stack segment like other auto
> variables */  *(str+1) = 'n';   /* No problem: String is now GnG */
> ```

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/5328