# Changing characters in a string by adding value causes runtime error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, runtime-error, character

I am trying to make a code which changes the letter in the character array.

Most of the codes are working well. However, when I try to change capital letters into small letters(or vice versa), the code doesn't work and the program ends.

I presume it is because the pointer cannot use itself or similar reason. But I can't point out the right reason.

I am worried if it is xy question, but please understand I don't want to upload the whole question since it is my assignment and I want to solve the problem by my self as much as I can, and I think it is the right way to learn program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void){
    //initialize
    char *ae = "sample";
    // for (){}
    ae[0] -= 36;//at this point, program stops
    // tried ae[0] = ae[0] -36 ; *ae = *ae - 36; and so on...
    printf("%c", ae[0] - 36);
}
```

Thank you for your time:)

Comment: @user3121023 Sorry, I am not used to coding term. What do you mean by literal and modify??

Comment: Use `char ae[] = "sample";` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between char\* and char\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564033/difference-between-char-and-char)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression...

```
char *ae = "sample";
```

...initializes the pointer with a [string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2245983/6865932), these are read-only and can't be modified. The expression `ae[0] -= 36;` attempts to change the first character of this string literal, but this is not allowed and causes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2397995/6865932).

Instead, use:

```
char ae[] = "sample";
```

In another note, subtracting `36` from an alphabetic character does not convert it to its upper case, at least not in **ASCII** encoding, you might have meant `32`.

Anyway, this is not very portable, you can use [`toupper()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) and [`tolower()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) from `<ctype.h>` library for a more robust option.

Comment: Thank you fro your help :) Your answer was very useful for me :):)

Comment: @JaehoSong, I'm glad I could help.