# toLower string in C 0xC0000005

Tags: c

well I've got this code that I'm trying to get working but no matter what I keep on getting that I am getting 0xC0000005

```
int main()
{
    if(stringContains("hello", "Hello world", FLAG_CASE_SENSITIVE))
    {
        printf("Works");
    }
    
    printf("%i", stringContains("hello", "Hello world", FLAG_CASE_SENSITIVE));
    return 0;
}

#define FLAG_CASE_INSENSITIVE 0
#define FLAG_CASE_SENSITIVE 1
    
typedef enum { false, true } bool;
    
bool stringContains(char* needle, char* stack, int type);
char* toLower(char* s);
    
bool stringContains(char* needle, char* stack, int type)
{
    if(type == FLAG_CASE_SENSITIVE)
    {
        return (strstr(toLower(stack), toLower(needle)) != 0) ? true : false;
    }
    return (strstr(stack, needle) != 0) ? true : false;
}

char* toLower(char* s) {
    for(char *p=s; *p; p++) *p=tolower(*p);
    return s;
}
```

I must admit, I am pretty basic when it comes to C

Comment: You are passing *string literals* to functions that attempt to modify them. String literals are read only.

Comment: OT: You need to declare functions before they are called. That is, move the forward declarations to the top of the file.

Comment: @kaylum I did, it's just I merged few files, thats why it looks like this.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hmm alright, what should I do? I'm really new to this :(

Comment: Either don't pass string literals to those functions, or modify the functions so that they don't attempt to modify the strings.  Personally, I prefer the latter approach.

Comment: First of all, there is no reason for the functions to modify the input. You are only *checking* something. This procedure should not be destructive.

Comment: @TomislavTomiNikolic Next time please show the exact code that you have compiled and run that can reproduce the problem. It is very important as details matter in programming. As for the string literal problem, see: [Difference between char* and char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564033/difference-between-char-and-char)

Answer (score 1):

`Try to declare functions which will accept literals as` const`:

```
bool stringContains(const char *needle, const char *stack, int type);
```

Then you will be warned if the `const` will be stripped when you call another functions.

https://godbolt.org/z/x4z5vE

You will need to get rid of this problem. Cast will not help as it will only silence the warning but not change anything regarding the strings, so you will need to create the writable copies of the strings.

```
bool stringContains(const char* needle, const char* stack, int type)
{
    
    if(type == FLAG_CASE_SENSITIVE)
    {
        char *haystack = strdup(stack);
        char *newneedle = strdup(needle);
        char *result = NULL;
        if(haystack && newneedle)
            result = strstr(toLower(haystack), toLower(newneedle));
        free(newneedle);
        free(haystack);
        return !!result;
    }
    return !!strstr(stack, needle);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Kvdxq3