# In C is it possible to allocate a `char[]` on the heap?

Tags: arrays, c, malloc

I am currently trying to learn C so apologies if this is a stupid question.  There are many previous questions that highlight specifically that `char* != char[]`.

- Example 1 - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186765/what-is-the-difference-between-char-array-and-char-pointer-in-c)
- Example 2 - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s)
- Example 3 - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564033/difference-between-char-and-char)

However all examples I can find of heap arrays appear to use `char*` e.g.

```
char *heap_string = (char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char) +  1);
```

So my question is then; is it possible to have a `char[]` on the heap (is that even meaningful?) Or are `char[]` only stack objects ?

(I should add I don't have a specific objective here I am merely trying to study the language / understand whats going on under the hood).

Comment: its your memory and how you choose to interpret it

Comment: It doesn't matter what you call the memory allocated on the heap - the pointer returned by `malloc()` *et al* is still a pointer.

Comment: First thing first, there are no `char[]` objects in C. All of the examples have objects of type `char[N]`, where `N` is some integer constant (specific for each variable). `char[]` is just a shorthand notation that can (but doesn't have to) be used to *declare* them.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI - Thank you for the clarification - that makes sense !

Comment: Objects on the heap are not declared. `malloc` returns a pointer and you interpret that pointer as pointing to an object of a specific type. That type can be `char[N]`. So you have two objects, `char[N]` that lives on the heap, and `char*` that lives on the stack and holds the address of that heap object.

Comment: Unrelated but your current allocation could be reduced to: `char *heap_string = malloc(sizeof(char[50 + 1]));` - or just `char *heap_string = malloc(50 + 1);`

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, `char[]` is an incomplete array type. So technically speaking any object of `char[N]` type is also `char[]` type.

Comment: Not exactly, @tstanisl.  If you're going to get that technical then `char[N]` is a type *compatible with* incomplete type `char[]`, but no object has an incomplete type, nor more than one type.  The type of an object is one of its identifying characteristics.

Comment: Heap and stack are not C language concepts, but if you divide memory into those categories then to which one do you attribute objects with static storage duration, such as those declared at file scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array of `char` is an object, and an *object* in C is “region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values” (C 2018 3.15). So, when you allocate memory with `malloc`, that memory can be used as a `char []`. C 2018 7.22.3 says the returned pointer (if successful) may be “used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated).”

Given there is an array of `char` at the pointed-to location, should we choose to use it as such, the issue is that we typically use arrays by pointing to their individual elements. After a successful `char *p = malloc(50);`, there is an array of 50 `char` at `p`, and we can access its elements using `p[i]`.

If you want to refer to the array using the type `char []` or `char [50]`, you can do this with a pointer to that type, using `char (*p)[] = malloc(50);` or `char (*p)[50] = malloc(sizeof *p);`.

With these, there are limited ways to use the array without accessing its individual elements. For historic reasons, C is designed for accessing arrays primarily via their individual elements, not as whole objects.

This does not give you a name for the array; you do not have some variable `A` that is the array. However, you can use `*p` as if it were a name for the array. This difference is of little consequence; there is very little you could do with a name `A` for the array that you cannot do with `*p`.

One difference would be in taking the size of the array. If you have some array declared as static or automatic instead of dynamically allocated, you can take its size with `sizeof A`. With the `char (*p)[50]` declaration above, you can also take the size with `sizeof *p`. With the `char *p` or `char (*p)[]` declarations, you cannot get the size of the array with `sizeof`. However, this generally does not matter because, with a dynamically allocated array, the program is usually handling its size itself. It had to pass the size to `malloc`, so it has that value when the array is created and merely needs to keep it for other uses if desired. So a program that is dynamically allocating arrays does not need to use `sizeof` on them.

Comment: does it mean that a pointer returned from `malloc()` is technically pointing to an array of *all* types?

Comment: @tstanisl: The pointer may be used to access an array (or single object) of any type with a satisfied alignment requirement. (`malloc` returns an address satisfying the fundamental alignment requirement, so it can be used for all the fundamental types.) Depending on how you interpret C’s rules about effective types, it is not actually pointing to an array of any particular type until you do something to treat it as such an array.

Comment: operation `p[idx]` is equivalent to `*(p + idx)`. Does it mean that a pointer arithmetics sets the type of an object to an array type?

Comment: @tstanisl: The rules have some complications, including dependency on whether you are using a character type and whether you are reading or writing. For more information, see the rules about effective type in the C standard or search Stack Overflow for “[C] "effective type"” or post a question.

Comment: @tstanisl Not the pointer arithmetic but de-referencing and storage. C17 6.5 "If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then the type of the lvalue becomes the effective type of the object for that access and for subsequent accesses that do not modify the stored value." A chunk returned from malloc is an object with no declared type. The rules are muddy about how to treat array objects differently than single "scalar" objects of the type of the array item.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to place a `char[50]` on the heap, but it's obnoxious and confusing, and not especially meaningful. Off the top of my head, I believe the syntax is:

```
char (*heap_string)[50] = (char (*)[50])malloc(50*sizeof(char));
```

Note  that in your code, the type of `heap_string` is a "pointer to an unknown number of `char`".  In this code here, the type of `heap_string` is a "pointer to an unknown number of `char[50]`".  So `heap_string[0]` refers to the first `char[50]` array, and `heap_string[1]` and `heap_string+1` both refer to the second `char[50]` array (or would, if we had allocated room for it).

In general, devs find *pointers* to arrays very confusing, and are almost guaranteed to write bugs, so nobody does this. Worse, now the code *only* works for `char[50]`, and not any other length, so the code is also less flexible and less powerful. So again, nobody does this.

Also note that since it's `char[50]`, there is no extra room for a trailing null character, like you have in your sample code.

Comment: O wow yer that appears to work and feels very dirty:
```
    (*heap_string)[0] = 'a';
    (*heap_string)[1] = 'b';
    (*heap_string)[2] = '\0';
    printf("The memory location of ptr is: %p\n", (void *)heap_string[0]);
    printf("The memory location of ptr is: %p\n", (void *)heap_string[1]);
    printf("The value is: %s\n", *heap_string);
--------------
The memory location of ptr is: 0x7ff458705eb0
The memory location of ptr is: 0x7ff458705ee2
The value is: ab
```

Thank you for explaining this !

Comment: @EricPostpischil: (A) You're being overly pedantic. "allocating things on the heap" has a well understood and specific meaning. The fact that the C++ spec doesn't use the term "heap" is irrelevant. (B) You're also wrong. So far as I can tell, no major implementation of a free store has ever used a heap data structure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Heap_(data_structure)#Origin_of_Phrase_.22the_Heap.22

Comment: There is no need to cast the result from `malloc()`. It just adds pointless noise to the code. Better do: `char (*heap_string)[50] = malloc(sizeof *heap_string);`

Comment: I would not say it is confusing. I would rather say that understanding of "array types" is rather limited among C developers.

Comment: @tstanisl: I have many many years of C++ experience. I have absolutely no problems with arrays of arrays.  But even I have to stop when thinking about *pointers* to arrays.

Comment: @tstanisl - are you sure that code is correct, I get a compiler error when I try to use it `cannot initialize a variable of type 'char (*)[50]' with an rvalue of type 'void *'`

Comment: @gowerc, It is. See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/89Tjhah8Y). You must be using C++ compiler. Don't do it because C is not a subset of C++.

Comment: Apologies you were right, I was using `gcc` which apparently on mac is mapped to -> `Apple clang version 14.0.3` though because I was using extension `.C`  instead of `.c`  clang decided it would compile as c++ :(

Answer (score 1):

It is true that `char*` and `char[]` are different things. A `char[]` with no size specified is an incomplete array since it does not specify a size. Usually we can't use such an array, `char arr[];` would lead to a compiler error.

However as a special rule, if we provide an initializer then the array will get a suitable size to contain all the items in the initializer list: `char array[] = "hi"` actually gives us a  `char[3]` (2 letters + null terminator).

Another special rule is that when we write an array as a function parameter, that parameter gets implicitly adjusted to a pointer to the first item of that array. Therefore we can write `void func (char array[])` and then `array` turns into a `char*`. This adjustment (sometimes referred to as "array decay") happens no matter what size we specify for the array parameter, which is why C allows an empty `[]` there.

Since a `malloc` call doesn't fit either of the above usages of the `char[]` syntax, we cannot really specify an array of incomplete type declared dynamically. We could however create a pointer to such an array:

```
char (*heap_string)[] = malloc(50*sizeof(char) +  1);
```

Since (`sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to always be 1, we may just as well just do `malloc(50+1)`. Or `malloc(sizeof(char[50+1]))`. All equivalent.

Here `heap_string` is a cumbersome pointer to incomplete type. Meaning we'll have to write `(*heap_string)[i] = 'a';` each time we want to access the array. That's inconvenient and hard to read, so therefore the convension is to just use `char* heap_string = malloc(...` instead.

The above syntax becomes handy for multi-dimensional arrays however. We can then skip out the left-most array bound:

```c
int (*arr)[2][3] = malloc( sizeof(arr[1][2][3]) );
```

Then we can access this array as `arr[i][j][k]`. Skipping one dimension in the pointer means we don't have to do `(*arr)[i][j][k]` which would have been ugly and cumbersome.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any practical difference then between `void func (char x[])` and `void func (char * x)` ?  My naive assumption would be that the former works with types `char (*)[N]` and the latter doesn't ?

Comment: @gowerc Those two examples are 100% equivalent. The "adjustment" happens early on during compile-time. You could check out this example https://godbolt.org/z/cYK111WzW. We can't declare a plain `char[]` in main() so I used a pointer to one. The compiler treats the arrays and pointers as different types while in main(). But inside the function, they are both `char*` because of adjustment.