# uint32_t equivalent for strings and other data types

Tags: string, types, uint32

my problem is regarding types of variables/values in a file that defines a message which can be exchanged and should be understood by code in multiple programming languages.
The example I received was the following:

```
uint32_t x
uint32_t y
```

The explanation for this was that uint32_t type will be adapted automatically from the java/python/c++ code.
As I am a new programmer, I am now confused how to do this for other types of variables, especially for exchanging Strings. As it isn't obvious to my to which programming language this might belong or what to research, I am glad for every hint on how to search for this and how to exchange Strings.
I already tested it with a char like this

```
char test
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how specific the question was to this coding project or if someone else will ever have this issue but nevertheless here is was worked for me in the end after searching trough other messages of this type in other projects related to mine.

For a string you simply have to use

```
char* test
```

I fount [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823249/what-is-a-char/6823292) question afterwards so it seems like this char* is something frequently used in C++.

Comment: i never coded in c++, but apparently the * means the following there: "Using a * says that this variable points to a location in memory. In this case, it is pointing to the location of the string "test"."